# Orientdb : how find edge between multiple vertices

Tags: orientdb

I want to find every edges connect by Vertices with the name "bob".

What can't be the correct SQL request?

Comment: Please provide some more information about your problem. What have you tired so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this query:

`select expand(bothE()) from User where name = "bob"`

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE:**

Try this query:

`select * from E where in.name = "bob" and out.name = "bob"`

Comment: Hi, with this request i have :  all edges where Vertex in OR  Vertex out whith the name is bob.    I whant all edges where Vertex in AND  Vertex out With the name is bob.

Comment: name = "bob" property is on edge or on vertex?

Comment: Is a vertex property.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please try it and let me know. Thanks.